# Docker compose recreates one dependency but not the other

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have a compose file where my own application depends on two other services:

```
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:15-alpine

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox:4.8.1-20230306
    shm_size: 2gb

  application:
    build:
      context: application
    depends_on:
      - database
      - selenium
```

Now, this all runs fine and I can run `docker compose up` without issue.

What baffles me though is that when I use `docker compose up` a second time, or use `docker compose run application` to run a one-off command, docker seems to magically detect that my postgresql is running and ignores it, but it then recreates the selenium service...

```
# docker compose run application python manage.py import_easypay_data -v 3
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Container domainservicebus-database-1  Running
 ⠿ Container domainservicebus-selenium-1  Recreated
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container domainservicebus-selenium-1  Started
```

Now I know about `--no-deps` and `--no-recreate` and such, but in an ideal world, I would like docker to treat the selenium service in the exact same way as the postres service, and I simply cannot find how or where that is configured...

EDIT:

- Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
- Docker Compose version v2.16.0

Comment: Interesting! What docker (and compose) version are you using? I couldn't reproduce this behavior on my older setup

Comment: Added versions to the question. Interesting to hear you seem to not have the issue. What versions do you have?

Answer (score 0):

you are using "run" without using flag "--rm" which i think makes some containers enabel to be still working behind without exiting.
so after working with docker, try to make it "down" and clear containers :

```
sudo docker container prune
```

after that you can "up" it again.
and also some tags are available for example for mysql docker-compose file that maybe possible for postgres to like this :

```
mysql:
 image: mysql:latest
 restart: always
```

hope to be useful